# How to find the WPF Custom Control template in Add new Item dialog?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, custom-controls, visual-studio-2015

When I want to create a custom control(not user control),I can't find `Custom Control` tempalte in  `Add New Item` dialog .

How to find or add the `custom control` template for WPF in `Add New Item` dialog ?

[image: Add new Item no <code>CustomControl</code>]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A WPF Custom Control is a project type; you add one to a Solution with Add / New Project. It looks like you're trying to add a single file to a Project with Add / New Item.

Answer (score 3):

If you have existing project and you don't want to reacreate it, add following line to `<PropertyGroup>` in your .csproj file.

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>{60dc8134-eba5-43b8-bcc9-bb4bc16c2548};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

Then add following line to `AssemblyInfo.cs` to make sure your themes are working

```
[assembly: ThemeInfo( ResourceDictionaryLocation.None, ResourceDictionaryLocation.SourceAssembly)]
```